# Firefox auto form filler extension

Tags: firefox, forms

For a long time, I used LastPass as my password manager. But the newest version is very bloated and slow, and finally I gave it up in favour of KeePass. But I miss LastPass' form-filling capabilities - I could define several profiles with different names, addresses and so on. Is there an extension that does that? I've tried [Autofill Forms](https://add0n.com/autofillforms-e10s.html) but it's a bit buggy.

Comment: Did you try RoboForm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/), which has both the password manager and form-filling functionality that I wanted, as a drop-in replacement for LastPass. It's got a browser extension, an Android app, and a web interface. And it's under active development.